# disable publish button until condition is not met

Tags: hooks, publish, buttons

I currently wrote a plugins to customize my wordpress website. I surprisly find it easy to do many things with hook. Now I want to make author not be able to push publish button if no category is choosed ( I don't want uncategorized article and force author to choose something ) How I can did this with a little message telling to the user to choose a category when he try to click publish button if no category are checked.

thanks

Comment: You will need Javascript. How far can you get on this without help?

Comment: you can force category selection before loading the post edit screen, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14405/4771).

Comment: s_ha_dum : not really far because I don't know where to start ... and probably less far if you tell me I really need to use javascript. Possible to only use php and hook ?    Milo 10:  If I can avoid popup a page before to entered in the articles form will be great. If it's can happen directly on the same page.

Comment: Unless you use Javascript, you can (probably) remove the publish button if no category is selected, but  you would have to save with a category, then publish in a second action. The best approach would be PHP and Javascript, honestly.

Comment: [Here is a preview of what you are getting into](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104951/21376) unless there are changes in the latest version that might make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found somethings. Not directly by cod it but I find a already wrote plugins for this.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-post-category-selection/

Hope it's will help others wordpress user.